# Integrating react-dnd with react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd, react-data-table-component

Has anyone been able to get react-dnd to work with https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component or with https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd?

Trying to see how to make them talk to each other, but haven't found any examples or anything that would point me in the right direction. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes, but because these libraries work on data and not on the DOM, and **react-data-table-component** is kind of a closed box, I haven't found a way to get them talking with each other, just looking for someone to point me in the right direction (maybe some article somewhere), that's all.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Figured out it's not possible with react-data-table-component, so ended up using **react-table** library instead!